# Google Cloud Compute , PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform

Following all the links at stackoverflow, I have installed and setup postgresql on compute instance. Its up and running with the below config -

```
pg_hba.conf -- 
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            ident
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0            md5

-bash-4.2$ cat postgresql.conf | grep listen
listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
```

I did a restart after the listen IP and pg_hba.conf changes. Post that the service is up and running -

```
[xxxxxxx_gmail_com@python-postgres ~]$ sudo systemctl status postgresql-9.4
postgresql-9.4.service - PostgreSQL 9.4 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-9.4.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2015-02-18 13:07:55 UTC; 12min ago

[xxxxxxx_gmail_com@python-postgres ~]$ netstat -a --numeric-ports | grep 5432
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:5432               [::]:*                  LISTEN
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     108412   /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

Still the ports are not visible externally and I cant connect to the DB using PGadmin3..

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-02-18 13:23 UTC
Nmap scan report for 11x.21x.15x.10x.bc.googleusercontent.com (10x.15x.21x.11x)
Host is up (0.0013s latency).
Not shown: 996 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp   open   ssh
80/tcp   closed http
443/tcp  closed https
3389/tcp closed ms-wbt-server
```

Any ideas on this?

Thanks,
Manish

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't mention anything about setting up a firewall on the compute instance. According to [Google Compute Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#firewalls) :

> By default, all incoming traffic from outside a network is blocked and no packet is allowed into an instance without an appropriate firewall. To allow incoming network traffic, you need to set up firewalls to permit these connections. Each firewall represents a single rule that determines what traffic is permitted into the network.

So you have to at least setup a firewall with the incoming traffic open on port 5432. Check out [This documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#firewalls_1) and note also that usually platform firewalls are not visible in any way to the hosted instance.

Use Command -

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create postgres --allow tcp:5432 icmp
```

Comment: [xxxxxxx_gmail_com@python-postgres ~]$ sudo systemctl status firewalld
firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: [xxxxxxx_gmail_com@python-postgres ~]$ sudo systemctl status iptables
iptables.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: I disabled iptables and firewalld to ensure that no packets are dropped. Also I have a Public IP on the Compute Instance.

Comment: Google Cloud has a firewall that is completely separate from your operating system firewall. You can at least set a firewall up with gloud command. [Link to installing gloud command-line tools](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gcloud-compute/#install). The second link in my answer has documentation on setting it up. Note that if you do not set it up **no packet is allowed in**.

Comment: Thanks... gcloud compute firewall-rules create postgres --allow tcp:5432 icmp  solved the issue